# Flask Blueprint pass object to another file

Tags: python, flask

I'm using python selenium to make a webservice when it's called will execute some instructions to a page, but the problem is pass 'driver' class to another page using flask blueprint.

main.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as chrome_options
from classes.send_message import send_message
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

app.register_blueprint(send_message)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    logging.info('START APP')

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
    options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\myuserpath........")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)

    driver.get("https://example.com")

    app.run(host='192.168.50.1', port='11111',debug=False)
```

send_message.py

```
from flask import Blueprint
#from flask import current_app as app    
send_message = Blueprint('send_message', __name__)

@send_message.route("/SendPostMessage")
def sendMessage():
    side_panel = driver.find_element_by_id('menutop') # error here!!!
```

error:

```
  File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\rararara\classes\send_message.py", line 8, in sendMessage
    side_panel = driver.find_element_by_id('menutop')
NameError: name 'driver' is not defined
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the app object as a context:

```
...
driver.get("https://example.com")
app.driver = driver
app.run(host='192.168.50.1', port='11111',debug=False)
```

and then

```
from flask import current_app as app
...
@send_message.route("/SendPostMessage")
def sendMessage():
    side_panel = app.driver.find_element_by_id('menutop')
```

Comment: ok it worked, but I forgot to ask how  implement get and post